# How to Enable "reduced redundancy" on Laravel Storage

Tags: laravel, flysystem

I'm using Laravel 5.2 Filesystem Storage Class.

And here's how I put the object to my bucket:

```
Storage::put('s3')->put([$path, $content]);
```

How do I add StorageClass => REDUCED_REDUNDANCY in the option?
I tried to add on config/filesystem.php but it doesn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.
We can actually put the third array on put() method if we include getDriver

```
Storage::disk('s3')
->getDriver()
->put([$path, $resource, 'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY']);
```